# Search on addAjaxFilterBox defineRelationship fields in ajaxCrud

Tags: ajax, list, select, crud

AjaxCrud has one problem. When you create a relationship, search is created with input text fields.

So if you have a relationship to another table, you can't use the description field of the foreign table. You must search using the ID of the foreign key. *FAIL*

Well, my users don't even know there are ID Fields.

So I really needed to change those input texts with  fields, using foreign key table values.

My solution is right below.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed ajaxCRUD.class.php

near line 1191, between

```
$top_html .= "</select>\n";
            } and `else{
                $custom_class = "";
                if ($this->display_field_with_class_style[$filter_field] != '') {`
```

I've inserted this code:

```
else
            if (is_numeric($found_category_index))
            {
                $category_field_name = $this->category_field_array[$found_category_index];
                $category_table_name = $this->category_table_array[$found_category_index];
                $category_table_pk   = $this->category_table_pk_array[$found_category_index];
                $order_by = '';
      if ($this->category_sort_field_array[$found_category_index] != ''){
          $order_by = " ORDER BY " . $this->category_sort_field_array[$found_category_index];
      }

      $whereclause  = '';
      if ($this->category_whereclause_array[$found_category_index] != ''){
          $whereclause = $this->category_whereclause_array[$found_category_index];
      }

                $dropdown_array = q("SELECT $category_table_pk, $category_field_name FROM $category_table_name $whereclause $order_by");

                $top_html .= "<br><select name=\"$filter_field\" onChange=\"filterTable(this, '" . $this->db_table . "', '$filter_field', '$extra_query_params');\">";
                $top_html .= "<option value=\"\">==Select==</option>\n";

                foreach ($dropdown_array as $dropdown)
                {
          $dropdown_value = $dropdown[$this->category_table_pk_array[$found_category_index]];
          $dropdown_text  = $dropdown[$this->category_field_array[$found_category_index]];
          $top_html .= "<option value=\"$dropdown_value\" >$dropdown_text</option>\n";
      }

                $top_html .= "</select>\n";

            }
```

And I've included this line `$found_category_index = array_search($filter_field, $this->db_table_fk_array);`

after this one: `foreach ($this->ajaxFilter_fields as $filter_field){`
near line 1156.

It goes through relationship array and creates a selected based on query result.

Vote if this one solved your problem. Share if you get any better solution.